# Confusion over initialisation of an enum class and assign TemperatureUnit.Kelvin to self (self = .Kelvin)

Tags: swift, enums, initialization

I was reading "Swift programming language 2.1" and have encountered the following code. I was just wondering what the keyword "`self`" is referring to? When I create an instance of TemperatureUnit, `var measuringUnit = TemperatureUnit(symbol: "k")`, this would in turn assign `.Kelvin` to `self`, but does it mean that only `case Kelvin`  exist for this particular instance of `TemperatureUnit` enum?

case Celsius and case Fahrenheit would no longer exist, at least for this instance of `TemperautureUnit` anyway, is this correct? Could someone please kindly explain it to me?

```
enum TemperatureUnit {
    case Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit
    init?(symbol: Character){
        switch symbol{
        case "k":
            self = .Kelvin
        case "c":
            self = .Celsius
        case "f":
            self = .Fahrenheit
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

var measuringUnit = TemperatureUnit(symbol: "k")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `self` refers to the enum instance that the `init()` function is creating for you.
2. `init()` only initialized the enum instance. You can still change the enum value later on as long as you claimed `measuringUnit` as variable. i.e. `measuringUnit = .Celsius`